# How to make no rows display in mysql when the IN is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have used the following query to get the data from database its working fine when the IN () is not empty but how can i restrict it as displaying no rows When my IN is empty

```
SELECT `id`, `date`, `user`, `type`, `module`, `action`, `ip_address`, `log` 
FROM `task_logs` 
WHERE `type`='E' AND ((`task` IN () AND (`module` = 'task' OR `module` = 'plan')) OR (`task` IN (35) AND `module` = 'regular_task')) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: I imagine your problem is the `or` not the `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in Postgres:

```
select *
from <table>
where id in (null)
```

Edit: But you have to take care that `id` is never `null` though :-)

Comment: Even if `id` is null `id in (null)` will fail anyway

Comment: Ya the ID is a primary key and ur answer is correct...!

Comment: If `id` is nullable or not it does not make any difference

Comment: Ya i got ur point and its working fine thanx fr ur help friend